# Laravel: Pessimistic Locking

Tags: laravel

I am trying to understand how laravel pessimistic locking works.

This is my case:

- There are 2 users A and B.
- Step 1: A opens edit/update form for X model. (Old X)
- Step 2: A goes get a cup of coffee.
- Step 3: B opens edit/update form for X model. (Old X)
- Step 4: B submits to update X model. (Updated X)
- Step 5: A backs to desk, edits info and submits to update X model. (Old X, not Updated X, should be Updated X)

So, my questions are:

- Q1: How sharedLock() method works in this case?
- Q2: Which step we should run sharedLock() method? (Step 1?)
- Q3: How lockForUpdate() method works in this case?
- Q4: Which step we should run lockForUpdate() method? (Step 1?)

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: If it was pessimistic locking, the user B would not be able to start editing the entity.

Comment: @zerkms: so when do we use lock? In step 1 when retrieving model X to update?

Comment: I don't know laravel, I just corrected the terminology.

Comment: oh, thank you @zerkms

Comment: Hello? Can someone help me this? I can't find the answer because laravel doc does not seem to be clear